# Problem printing number of records added to database

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

How do I print the total number of records added in the database? In my case it's the records of both Nation 1 and Nation 2. Each nation has 20 records, so the total is 40 records, but I only see 20 records added with my code cursor.rowcount (40 records are entered correctly in the database)

I try this, but it's not ok, it just tells me the record number of one of the two Nations, and not you both in their total (I would like Nation 1 + Nation 2):

```
records_added_Nations = 0
print ("Record inserted successfully", cursor.rowcount)
records_added_Nations = records_added_Nations + 1
cursor.close ()
```

The code of the added records is this:

```
#NATION 1   
sqlite_insert_query_Nation1 = 'INSERT INTO Nation (Name_Nation) VALUES (?);'
count_Nation1 = cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_Nation1, Values_Nation1)
con.commit()

#NATION 2   
sqlite_insert_query_Nation2 = 'INSERT INTO Nation (Name_Nation) VALUES (?);'
count_Nation2 = cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_Nation2, Values_Nation2)
con.commit()
```

Comment: `count_Nation1 + count_Nation2`?

Comment: "cursor.rowcount" is the number of rows affected by the **last** operation. Each "executemany" is an operation.

Comment: @Barmar I tried print ("Record inserted successfully", count_Nation1 + count_Nation2), but it doesn't work, there is an error. Could you show me the code please? Thanks

Comment: @Michael Butscher  I see. What is the code to print the total of all added records of all operations? Thanks

Comment: Why are you assigning the result of `cursor.executemany()`? I can't find any documentation saying that it returns anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `cursor.rowcount` after each operation, and total them.

```
#NATION 1   
sqlite_insert_query_Nation1 = 'INSERT INTO Nation (Name_Nation) VALUES (?);'
cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_Nation1, Values_Nation1)
count_Nation1 = cursor.rowcount
con.commit()

#NATION 2   
sqlite_insert_query_Nation2 = 'INSERT INTO Nation (Name_Nation) VALUES (?);'
cursor.executemany(sqlite_insert_query_Nation2, Values_Nation2)
count_Nation2 = cursor.rowcount
con.commit()

print ("Records inserted successfully", count_Nation1 + count_Nation2)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is a problem. In this way, the same cursor.rowcount of one (1) nation is not repeated twice? The result will be 40 ok, but why is the same nation repeated twice? A clone is created. The result 40 is correct, but false. There are no assignments for count_Nation1 and count_Nation1: they have the same same cursor.rowcount

Comment: If you're getting the same nation twice, it must be in both `Values_Nation1` and `Values_Nation2`. Why shouldn't it be inserted twice? If you want to prevent that, you should add a unique index on the `Name_Nation` column. Then you'll get an error if you try to add a duplicate.

Comment: They are 2 different nations, even though they both have 20 records. In my case count_Nation1 has 20 records, and count_Nation2 also has 20 records. Doubt came to me for this reason. Let's pretend that count_Nation1 has 20 records and count_Nation2 has 23 records: your code would show 43 added records right? Or 40? Can you double check the code please? Thanks

Comment: It should show 43.

Comment: Considering they have the same record number and similar name (for example purposes), I thought there was a little misunderstanding or I didn't explain well (I'm writing with google translator). So you confirm that if count_Nation1 has 20 records and count_Nation2 has 23 records, the result with your code is 43 and not 40? The doubt came to me because count_Nation1 and count_Nation1 both have cursor.rowcount, but they are 2 different things

Comment: `cursor.rowcount` is the count from the last query. So each time you do `cursor.execute()` or `cursor.executemany()`, it changes what the next `cursor.rowcount` will be.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I vote your answer and assign the answer as a solution. Thanks

Comment: If it's not a hassle, can you help me with this question as well please? It would be the same question, but for the columns. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763096/what-is-the-correspondent-of-cursor-rowcount-for-columns-and-how-to-set-the-choi